# SQL query to get items excluding already fetched items

Tags: sql-server, linq

I need sql query to get random items from a table excluding items which are previously fetched in the same manner..

Comment: Are you trying to do this all as one query or resupplying the list of elements to a secondary query?

Comment: @Gerik I would like it in a same query..

Comment: You really need to provide more information? Do you just want 1 random every time? Do you wanna select this one random excluding what you previously showed?

Answer (score 0):

Ive tried to answer your solution the best way i can think of now. However there are still some unclear questions which im not taking into account such as;

> 1. What do you do when you run out of previously selected values? Then you wont return anything? Cause at some point you have selected all values randomly.
> 2. How many items should it select and what is the specific term of "previously"

**Test data**

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.randomitems (namesused nvarchar(50))
CREATE TABLE dbo.randomlist (namesused nvarchar(50))
CREATE TABLE dbo.randoms (Names nvarchar(50))

insert into dbo.Randoms (Names) values ('a'), ('u'), ('p'), ('g'),
('j'), ('k'), ('l'), ('t')
```

**SQL Script**

```
declare @randomitem nvarchar(50)
declare @firstrun int = (select count(*) from dbo.randomlist)



if(@firstrun = 0)
BEGIN
SELECT top 1 @randomitem=[Names]
  FROM   [LegOgSpass].[dbo].[Randoms]
  
  order by newid();
 
truncate table dbo.randomitems;
insert into dbo.randomitems
select @randomitem
;

select * from dbo.randomitems a
where not exists (select * from dbo.randomlist b where a.namesused = b.namesused);

insert into dbo.randomlist
select @randomitem;
END

if(@firstrun >= 1)
BEGIN
SELECT top 1 @randomitem=[Names]
  FROM   [LegOgSpass].[dbo].[Randoms]  a
  where not exists (select * from dbo.randomlist b where a.Names = b.namesused)
  
  order by newid();


truncate table dbo.randomitems;
insert into dbo.randomitems
select @randomitem
;

select * from dbo.randomitems a
where not exists (select * from dbo.randomlist b where a.namesused = b.namesused);

insert into dbo.randomlist
select @randomitem;
END
```

**SELECTS**

```
select * from  dbo.Randoms
select * from  dbo.randomitems
select * from  dbo.randomlist
```